# Page HTML dont working with the css i get an error

Tags: html, css

Hello i try to bulid a web and the css dont working with the html , what is the problem ???

I get a error message.

I hava a three files :

```
index.html
styles.css
main.js
```

Comment: Can you please post the head of your html to see how you import the stylesheet?

Comment: Yes here is the head tag :<head>
<title>Frist web site</title>
</head>

Comment: Kindly post add an example of what you've tried and what is not working to your question, thanks

Comment: So you don't link to the stylesheet anywhere with a ```<link/>``` tag?

Comment: Thanks everyone, someone answered me and solved the problem for me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to connect the HTML to CSS for them to work together, you need to add a link to the CSS inside the HEAD tag in the HTML:

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8"/>
<title></title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css"/> // Connect the HTML to CSS

</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```